Multiple Device Cve Custom KQL script
I'm trying to create a custom query that will list all devices with a specific tag showing all CVE's against each device with a set criteria.  In general, the query works but if a CVE has been detected against a device for a period of time, it will create multiple entries. I've tried using a Timestamp filter but this is hit or miss depending when the last checked in.
The query I have so far is as below
DeviceTvmSoftwareVulnerabilities
| join kind=inner(DeviceTvmSoftwareVulnerabilitiesKB) on CveId  
| join kind =inner(DeviceInfo) on DeviceId
| where DeviceManualTags contains "SupportTeamName"
| where Timestamp >= now(-2hours)
| where OSPlatform !contains "2012" and OSPlatform !contains "2008" and OSPlatform !contains "Windows10" and OSPlatform!contains "windows11"
| where VulnerabilitySeverityLevel contains "Critical" or VulnerabilitySeverityLevel contains "High"
| project Timestamp, DeviceName, OSPlatform,CveId, CvssScore, VulnerabilitySeverityLevel, PublishedDate, VulnerabilityDescription, RecommendedSecurityUpdate, DeviceManualTags

Anyone know of a better filter to only show unique CveID's per device.
Thanks in advance

Can you provide your sample input and expected output?

Example file upload to https://filebin.net/wgvn2dhungcen2pm/Advanced%20KQL%20.xlsx    What Im  trying to get all servers and unique CVE's but at present, CVE's are repeating adding extra entries on the report

@DavidWilson It's better to provide sample data as a formatted datatable statement. Also the link is dead anyway.

You should be able to get what you are after by replacing the last project line in your query with:
| summarize arg-max(Timestamp, *) by DeviceName, OSPlatform, CveId, CvssScore, VulnerabilitySeverityLevel, PublishedDate, VulnerabilityDescription, RecommendedSecurityUpdate, DeviceManualTags

This should give you the most recent row grouped by device, os platform, cve id, etc.
